# Recommendations for running Linux together with Windows 7 on Toshiba Satellite

Tags: windows-7, linux, toshiba-laptop

I have never installed Linux before, but I would like to run it on my Toshiba Satellite C660-1UJ next to the current Windows 7 Home Premium OS. I read some things about windows 7/8 making it difficult to run Linux on the same machine.

Does anyone have experience with this particular setup? Any recommendations for a specific version of Linux? What would be better in this case, dual boot or a virtual machine?

System Specs:

- Windows 7 Home Premium x64
- 4GB RAM
- Intel Core i3 CPU - 2.10 GHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to test how it behaves, without installing, you could go for a Live USB/CD, which allows to boot directly from the mass storage device or a CD (slower). It loads as usually into RAM, you can open preinstalled apps, connect to internet, if you configure it to be persistent you can save data diretly on the USB device from which you booted. Of course it's much better when is a standalone installation (you might install some video drivers, new apps, break and repair things as well). Most modern instalations of linux distributions (LinuxMint, Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Debian, Fedora, etc) take much of the work required for installation, and give you options where to install, choose a username/password, set the date and clock. However this means you should know already how a disk works and what are partitions, a good installation is a separate installation on a different partition (it can be created during installation, or you can create a new one from windows as well, as long as you have some free space ). As I remember, you can install Ubuntu in Windows, you can unninstall it from Control Panel, but it will not be as native and fast as the first approach.

I, personally, met linux first time with Ubuntu a few years ago, also used Lubuntu (computer resource friendly), Kubuntu (fancy interface), Debian, FreeBSD (this is another story), currently I have a Linux Mint Cinnamon. I recommend you to take a USB drive and install on it a live USB using tools like:

Unetbootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Universal USB installer http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Remember, that all linux distros are different, because of the interface they will have (gnome, KDE, Cinnamon, MATE, LXDE, XFCE: each has its own visual interface, some are fancy and resource hungry, some are nice and clean). Also different distros can differ by the package managers which are used to handle/install new programs, as well as filetype for install files (in windows they are like setup.exe), here they are "coolprogram.rpm" for some, "installation.deb" for others. Single applications can be launched from commandline with "./name_of_program" or just typing the name of the program if it was installed using normal ways, but all this stuff you will learn very soon, nothing complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If your new to linux maybe getting your feet wet in a virtual machine might be the better/safer choice until you understand ROOT and iptables.  You'd be safer behind the NAT.

Just about every linux distro I know of easily installs along side Windows for dual boot.  One of the most popular distro is also one of the easiest to start out on..linux Mint. It will dual boot very easy on its own the only interaction it may ask is what proportions youd like to divide up between the two. Simply boot from the live disk and hit install and mint will ask you if you want to erase the harddrive for single boot or place along side of Windows.

When you said you heard about it being difficult is only if you do the revers and try to install Windows on top of linux. Windows does not recognize the linux file system but linux has no problem reading Windows.

I am running linux Mint dual booted over the top of Windows 7 Ultimate as I type this. Had fresh install of mint over top of Windows in just about 20 minutes with very little interaction. You will see that it's easy. (I personally never tried to boot Windows on top of linux before but I can guarantee it would be 10x harder than linux over Windows.)